# select rows with same ID but different value in another column between two tables

Tags: sql

i have to similar tables table 1 and table 2 .I want to compare the 2 tables and show the rows that ID is the same but has a different value in another column.

table 1

| ID | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 221 | 1 |
| 341 | 1 |

and

table 2

| ID | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 221 | 0 |
| 341 | 1 |

the output should be like this:

| ID | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- |
| 221 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.active <> t2.active
```